# Javascript change the value of a variable without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, variables, node.js, socket.io

I'm using Socket IO for realtime information on my website, everything works fine, but under a certain circumstance I have to open a new connection, replacing the old. So I need to replace the variable that defines the session, is there a way to do this? whether it be reload that one particular javascript page, or update the variables on the page.

I include the javascript page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ws/data/data.js"></script>
```

on this page there are a number of variables called "socket" which is defined on the line above where I include that javascript page like so:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

on the page itself the variable is used in ways such as:

```
socket.on('connected', function () {
socket.emit("session", cookie('login'));
});
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: I use socket.io too but never need to replace any variables. See http://popped.at for reference. I may be misunderstanding, but usually socket.io self-resumes. i.e. if my server restarts, or the connection is broken, Socket.io will keep re-trying to connect. Is that your situation, or something else?

Comment: Yeah, it's suppose to reconnect automatically, but it doesn't seem to. The main issue I'm having is that when I have my website up, and the socket is connect, when I close my laptop and it goes to sleep, it disconnects. Now when I reopen the website, it doesn't reconnect so anything I do is not sent to the other users, and anything anyone does to me is not sent to me - since im not connected, unless I refresh the entire page, to reconnect.

Comment: Can you share your site url so I can take a look?

Comment: http://199.192.203.137
You will need to create an account.

Comment: When I force a new connection it will connect them, the problem still being the the code on my variables for socket on data.js page contain the variables for the old socket, when I put the "connect" event inside of a function, and call that function on reconnect, it fires the handler event as it should. So im not sure how to fix this, so I don't have to call the functions and everything for it to work..